# Facebook gif sharing on own host

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, animated-gif, giphy

I tried to use FB.ui and share method to share dynamic gif.

The image was hosted in my own server. After shared, I found it was in static image.

Is it possible to host the gif other than GIPHY.com and some related images hosting websites? Any settings than need to be configured in my server?

I have tried to add mime type and add same value for og:url and og:image in html head section. But all of them failed.

Any advise? Thanks.

The code is as simple as the followings.

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        link: 'http://MY DOMAIN/img/THE GIF.gif',
        caption: 'An example caption',
        href: 'http://MY DOMAIN/img/THE GIF.gif',
    }, function(response){});
});
```

Comment: Please show the codes. At this moment, there is only limited support of GIF by Facebook. Only specific hosts like GIPHY are supported. Did you try to share a link of GIPHY animated GIF instead?

Comment: Yes I tried shared GIPHY GIF and it works! Are there any references that shows only specific hosts are supported? Thanks!

Comment: According to NY Times, there are only a limited sites that supports this feature: http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/21/technology/personaltech/posting-animated-gifs-on-facebook.html?_r=0

Comment: I just searched the posts in Facebook. Just found some seems using their own gif? For example https://www.facebook.com/mlb/posts/10153836816337451